# Comparator interface's equals method, why it is always safe not to override Object.equals(Object)

Tags: java, equals, comparator

I'm currently studying the `Comparator` interface and noticed that in the documentation for [Comparator's equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method, it states

> Note that it is always safe not to override Object.equals(Object)

[image]

I have checked the implementation for the default `equals` method in `Object` class

[image]

So with the default implementation of `equals` method, it simply checks whether two instances points to the same object because `this == obj` tests for reference equality.

But what happen if I have two instances of `Comparator`, the result they return are identical, and I want to know if they are equivalent. If I dont override the default `Object's equals` method, then regardless of whether the result they return is equivalent or not, by using the default `Object's equals` method, `false` will always be returned. So is it still **always safe not to override the Object.equals(Object)**?

Comment: You should never *expect* comparators to override `equals()`. It's just a possible optimization.

Comment: @shmosel so it is ok to compare two instances of `Comparator` and return `false`, even if their implementation are identical?

Comment: Not if they're `==`, but otherwise yes.

Comment: ok, thanks for helping out :)

Comment: A `Comperator` is a way to "sort" some Objects. It has some requirements: Either an object is "less than" an other object or "greater than" an other object or equal. `equal` should return `true` if the `Comperator` returns 0 (both objects are equal), but this is not a requirement.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Youre getting confused. OP is asking about `Comparator.equals()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you mis-interpreted what java doc is saying:

> this method **can** return true **only** if the specified object is also a comparator and it imposes the same ordering as this comparator

Default implementation will return true **only** if it is exactly the same object, which by definition means that they both (actually single one) provide the same sorting order

This definition does not imply that it will return true for different comparators even if they provide the same sorting order, simple verification:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class TestComparator {
    static class Comparator1 implements Comparator<Integer> {
        @Override
        public int compare(final Integer o1, final Integer o2) {
            return Integer.compare(o1, o2);
        }
    }

    static class Comparator2 implements Comparator<Integer> {
        @Override
        public int compare(final Integer o1, final Integer o2) {
            return Integer.compare(o1, o2);
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Comparator1 c1 = new Comparator1();
        final Comparator1 c11 = new Comparator1();
        final Comparator2 c2 = new Comparator2();

        System.out.println(c1.equals(c1)); // true
        System.out.println(c1.equals(c11)); // false
        System.out.println(c1.equals(c2)); // false
    }
}
```

Default implementation **can** return true if comparators equivalent, also it **can** return false (if objects are different)

Note further, doc says:

> However, overriding this method may, in some cases, improve performance by **allowing programs to determine that two *distinct* comparators impose the same order**.

So, it is safe not to override, but it is not enough to guarantee that different but equivalent comparators will be compared properly

Comment: thanks for the clarification! I think I got it now. Its hard to read and understand the documentation because their wording is so concise. Thanks for helping out!